# Decode SMPP logs

Tags: smpp

I'm logging the traffic of an smpp connection to which messages are sent in order to be delivered.
The logs are something like :

```
Starting EnquireLinkSender for SMPP connector session: bics --> (enquirelink: (pdu: 0 15 0 1) )<-- (enquirelink_resp: (pdu: 16 80xxxxxx x x) )--> (enquirelink: (pdu: 0 15 x x) )<-- (enquirelink: (pdu: 16 15 x x) )
--> (enquirelink_resp: (pdu: 0 80xxxxxx x x) )
<-- (enquirelink_resp: (pdu: 16 80xxxxxx x x) )
--> (enquirelink: (pdu: 0 15 0 3) )
<-- (enquirelink: (pdu: 16 15 0 2) )
.
.
.
.
<-- (enquirelink_resp: (pdu: 16 80000015 0 5) )
--> (submit: (pdu: 0 4 0 6) (addr: 4 1 64111)  (addr: 1 1 320335200002)  (sm: enc: SCGSM msg: TextHere)  (opt: (short: (tlv: 516) 4)  ) )
```

How to decode this please ?

Answer (score 0):

what you see is in hex,
just use any converter from hex to string.